# Command-line argument files (@-files) for exec-maven-plugin

Tags: exec-maven-plugin

How can you add [command-line argument files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111) (@-files) to a mvn exec command line?

This does not work:

```
mvn -Dexec.mainClass="Main" -Dexec.args="@system.properties" exec:java
```